# EditText not using theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-theme, android-styles

My EditText isn't using the theme I've assigned to it.

Here is my activity's property in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="Index"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/IndexTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
</activity>
```

Here is my `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="IndexTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/IndexEditText</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/cursor_dark</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/text_c</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary</item>
</style>

<style name="IndexEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
</style>
```

And here is my `styles.xml` (v21):

```
<style name="IndexTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/IndexEditText</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

Yesterday it was working fine. Today I updated my support libraries from v22 to v23.1.1 and it not longer works.

Why?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: It's not applying the theme to the EditText.

Answer (score 2):

use both these 2 lines instead

```
<item name="editTextStyle">@style/IndexEditText</item>
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/IndexEditText</item>
```

It's works for me.